# Google Chrome incorrectly reporting width and height for images during load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

[Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) is wrongly reporting **width** and **height** values for images during, or just after, load time. [Jquery](http://jquery.com) is used in this code example:

```
<img id='image01' alt='picture that is 145x134' src='/images/picture.jpg' />

<script>
 var img = $( 'img#image01' )

 img.width() // would return 145 in Firefox and 0 in Chrome.
 img.height() // would return 134 in Firefox and 0 in Chrome.
</script>
```

If you put the script in a `$(function(){})` function, the result is the same. but if you run the code a few seconds after the page has loaded, [chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) returns the correct result.

```
<script>
  function example () {
    var img = $( 'img#image01' );

    img.width() // returns 145 in both Firefox and Chrome.
    img.height() // returns 134 in both Firefox and Chrome.
  }
  window.setTimeout( example, 1000 )
</script>
```

Also if you specify the **width** and **height** values in the *img* tag, the script seems to work as expected in both [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/firefox.html) and [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome).

```
<img id='image01' src='/images/picture.jpg' width=145 height=134 />
```

But as you cannot always control the html input, this is not an ideal workaround. Can [jQuery](http://jquery.com) be patched with a better workaround for this problem? or will I need to specify the **width and height** for every image in my code?

Comment: Now that's what sponsored tags are for!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your quoted code doing it inline is getting a reasonable result, as the image may well not be loaded before your code executes. You said that you put it in an `onload` handler and that also has the same result. Did you really mean an `onload` handler? Because I cannot replicate that result. Note that the jQuery `ready` function is **not** an `onload` handler, it happens much earlier than that. To ensure images are loaded, use the image's `load` event or the `window` `load` event. jQuery `ready` happens a lot earlier than that.

So this should work:

```
$(window).bind('load', function() {
    var img = $("#theimage");
    log("Width: " + img.width());
    log("Height: " + img.height());
});
```

...(where `log` is something that outputs to the page), and this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#theimage").bind('load', function() { // BUT SEE NOTE BELOW
        var img = $(this);
        log("Width: " + img.width());
        log("Height: " + img.height());
    });
});
```

...but this will not:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var img = $("#theimage");
    log("Width: " + img.width());
    log("Height: " + img.height());
});
```

...because it happens too soon.

**Edit**: I really, really should have said in the above: If you're looking the *image's* `load` event (rather than the `window` load event), you need to check to make sure the image hasn't already been loaded, because its `load` event may have already fired. That would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var img, imgElement;

    // Find the image
    img = $("#theimage");
    imgElement = img[0];
    if (imgElement && imgElement.complete) {
        // Already loaded, call the handler directly
        loadHandler.call(imgElement);
    }
    else {
        // Not loaded yet, hook the event
        img.bind('load', loadHandler);
    }

    function loadHandler() {
        var img = $(this);
        log("Width: " + img.width());
        log("Height: " + img.height());
        img.unbind('load', loadHandler);
    }
});
```

That will call `loadHandler` at the earliest opportunity, whether the image load won the race or the `ready` code won the race.

Comment: mm... I thought a jquery's $(function(){/* code */}) was an onload... u learn something new every day

Comment: but why does chrome and FF differ on this?

Comment: @Stefan: If you're doing it before the load event fires, it's a race condition, and the results will tend not to be deterministic. It may well be that Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine is just that much faster. ;-) (It is *freaky* fast.)

Comment: and here I was hating chrome for being faster at something

Comment: @Stefan: I just added something to the answer I really, really should have included originally: If you use the *image's* `load` event, you need to be sure to check the `complete` flag on the image element first to be sure it has *already* been loaded (e.g., to be sure it didn't win the race).

Answer (score 3):

This is not an error. The `img` element is 0x0 wide until the image is loaded. You should wait until the image is entirely loaded. Try something like this:

```
$("img#image01").load(function(){
  //do things here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#img2').show(function() {
    if( $.browser.safari ){
      alert ( $('#img2').width() );
    }
});
```

**.load** does not work for Chrome dimension so use **.show** ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put that code into

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

if that doesn't help, use jQuerys [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function

```
var $img = $('#image01'),
    iwidth = 0,
    iheight = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $img.load(function(){
        var img = $('#image01');

        img.removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height').css({width: '', height: ''});

        iwidth  = this.width;
        iheight = this.height;
   });
});

$img[0].src = '';
$img[0].src = $img[0].src;
```