# jQuery && Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

**This script works perfectly in all the browsers, except Google Chrome.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".banners-anim img").each(function(){
        var hover_width = $(this).width();
        var hover_height = $(this).height();
        var unhover_width = (hover_width - 30);
        $(this).width(unhover_width);
        var unhover_height = $(this).height();
        $(this).closest("li").height(unhover_height);
        var offset = "-" + ((hover_height - unhover_height)/2) + "px";
        $(this).closest("span").css({'position':'absolute', 'left':'0', 'top':'25px', 'width':'100%'});
        $(this).hover(function(){
            $(this).animate({width: hover_width, marginTop: offset}, "fast")
        },function(){
            $(this).animate({width: unhover_width, marginTop: 0}, "fast")
        });
    });
});
```

Chrome doesn't recognize changed image attributes.

When `width` of the img changes, `height` also changes. Even **not in Chrome**..

```
$(this).width(unhover_width);
var unhover_height = $(this).height();
```

`unhover_height` gives `0`.

**Full code of this script** (html included) - http://jsfiddle.net/BsqTe/

Please help to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035635/google-chrome-is-doing-things-wrong-again

Comment: OT, but all those `$(this)`'s make me wince. You're calling a function that constructs an object, using it, then throwing it away; then calling a function that constructs an object, then throwing it away; then calling a function that... You get the idea. Try `var $this = $(this)` at the top and then use `$this` instead.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - thats a good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're doing things with images from within the jQuery `ready` function, you need to remember that the images *may not be loaded yet*. The purpose of the jQuery `ready` function is to fire as soon as the DOM is ready, even if images are still loading. If you want to do something when all images have finished loading, use `window`'s `load` event instead:

```
$(window).load(yourFunctionHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to notice that images too have onload functions.  Furthermore, some IE versions have a peculiarity where if the image is already loaded, it will not fire any onload functions attached to the event after the fact.  So this little snippet should always insure that some function DoResize is called after the image has loaded

```
var DoResize = function() { ... }
var img = $(".find .your img");
img.bind('load', DoResize);
img.bind('error', DoResize); // in case picture fails to load, still resize
if (img.get(0).complete) { DoResize(); }
```