# Resizing images in Chrome using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, google-chrome, resize

I just ran into the weirdest of bugs today. I'm not sure if it's a bug in Chrome or something that I can work around but here goes.

I built a JQuery function to resize a set of images that are posted on a forum:

```
$(".post-message img.post-image").load(function(){
    $(this).each(function() {
        var maxWidth = 200;     
        if($(this).width() > maxWidth)
        {
            var factor = $(this).width() / maxWidth;
            var width = $(this).width();
            var height = $(this).height();
            $(this).css('width', width / factor);
            $(this).css('height', height / factor);
        }       
    });
});
```

The problem is that this only seems to work when I refresh the page. It doesn't work when you press previous or when you get linked to the page.

In chrome the `$(img).width()` property returns 0 in both cases when the function doesn't work.

This function performs as expected in IE9 and FF3

What can I do to fix this odd behavior?

Comment: i am assuming this is all within the document.ready or something of the sort?

Comment: No it is not. I got another answer from stack that suggest to execute the code on $(img).load() instead. The problem is actually that in both cases where it doesn't work `$(this).width()` returns 0. Let me add that to the question.

Comment: Try wrapping in it a document.ready or something and see if it works. Chrome could be executing the script before images are loaded, making their width 0.

Comment: Still the same issue, I've also already tried it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the contributions guys. A previous answer given on stack - that I apparently couldn't find this afternoon [jQuery && Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070316/jquery-google-chrome) - solved my problem!

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".post-message img.post-image").one("load", function(){
        $(this).each(function() {
            var maxWidth = 200;     
            if($(this).width() > maxWidth)
            {
                var factor = $(this).width() / maxWidth;
                var width = $(this).width();
                var height = $(this).height();
                $(this).css('width', width / factor);
                $(this).css('height', height / factor);
            }   
            console.log($(this).width())    
        });
    }).each(function() {
        if(this.complete) $(this).trigger("load");
    });
});
```

The code has to be executed on `$(window).load()` together with the provided code by karim79.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably because the images are being pulled up from the browser cache, and the `load` event is not triggering. The way around this is to manually trigger `load` if the images's `complete` properties have been set:

```
$(".post-message img.post-image").one("load", function(){
    $(this).each(function() {
        var maxWidth = 200;     
        if($(this).width() > maxWidth)
        {
            var factor = $(this).width() / maxWidth;
            var width = $(this).width();
            var height = $(this).height();
            $(this).css('width', width / factor);
            $(this).css('height', height / factor);
        }       
    });
}).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).trigger("load");
});
```

Comment: I still encounter the same issue. A quick debug shows that the function doesn't know the width of the image when the function triggers after coming back to the page. Also to emphasize the load event IS triggered and the callback in `$(this).each()` IS executed.

Answer (score 1):

Karmin is correct here. I ran into this problem a few years ago and ended up just not relying on img.load. His workaround for manually triggering the load event should work.

However...

Developers should do max-width or height in CSS in this scenario. In fact, it is good programming practice to do what one can in CSS before doing them in javascript.

Additionally, if one were to keep going with this solution, `var width` and `var height` should be placed outside of the if statement next to `var maxWidth`, and used wherever `$(this).width()` is called (including the initial check on line 4). Right now the code is unnecessarily creating a new jQuery object to get the height each time when it should have stored and used the value from the first check.

Comment: I see, let me check if I can insert that kind of optimization. Also check my answer, that's what worked for me in the end.